# Mod_rewrite redirect when URL parameters don't match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, httpserver

I need to redirect the page to homepage when its query string parameters don't match.

For example:

```
www.example.com/something?param1=1111&param2=2222&param3=3333&param4=4444 --> 
--> www.example.com
```

because param1 and param4 don't match.

I have written a little here:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} param1=1111
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !param4=1111
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.example.com [R]
```

but I'm sure that it isn't wokring properly because there are some cases when param4 is not present in the url at all and in that case it would go through the rewrite condition. Could anyone please help me to solve that issue as I'm very new to these configurations. And also, could someone explain to me which flag is better for this situation [R] or [R=301] and what's the difference between them? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **query string parameters don't match**? Can you provide couple of more examples to clarify it?

Comment: I mean when param1=param4 then query should stay the same for example
`www.example.com/something?param1=1111&param2=2222&param3=3333&param4=1111` or `www.example.com/something?param1=2222&param2=2222&param3=3333&param4=2222` these URLs has to stay unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little bit tricky to do this in `mod_rewrite`. You can use this back-reference based rule for that:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     (?:^|&)param1=([^&]*)
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)::(?:|.*&)param4=([^&]*)
RewriteCond %1::%2 !^(.*?)::\1$
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R]
```

`%1` represents parameter value of `param1` and `%2` represents parameter value of `param4`.